# CSS: Image won't upscale past its native resolution when placed inside a flexbox

Tags: html, css, image, flexbox

I'm writing a UI where I need to display an image and have an svg on top matching its size. In order to do so, I wrapped both elements inside a container and made them occupy `width: 100%` and `height: 100%`. Everything is contained inside a flexbox column, since there are more UI elements that I need to place.
I would like to have this container resize to fit as much height or width available while keeping the aspect ratio fixed.

I've almost gotten a full solution working in the following toy example:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<header>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
</header>

<html>
    <body>
        <div class="column">
            <div class="container">
                <img src="bitmap.png" alt="my_image">
                <svg>
                    <rect x="0" y="0" width="100%" height="100%" 
                    style="fill:none;stroke-width:6;stroke:rgb(0,0,255)" />
                </svg>
            </div>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

```
html, body {
    height: 100%;
}
body {
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
}
.column {
    height: 100%;
    width: 50%;
    background-color: lightgray;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: center;
}
.container {
    position: relative;
    max-height: 100%;
}
.container img {
    object-fit: contain;
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
}
.container svg {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
}
```

You can see it resizes properly when limited by [width](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6K3WP.png) or by [height](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dLvrL.png), keeping the svg on top of the image at all moments. However, when you increase the size, the image [stops growing when it hits its native resolution.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wmNO7.png).
If you set the property `flex-grow: 1` in the container, the image will grow behaving as I want it too, but the svg [won't overlay the image correctly anymore](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Se7KH.png).

[Here's](https://i.stack.imgur.com/J0PwU.png) the original 720x540 image I've used in the toy example, in case you want to try for yourself. Thanks in advance if you try to solve this! :)

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following CSS to resize the container to fit as much height or width available while keeping the aspect ratio fixed:

```
    .container {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  max-width: 100%;
  max-height: 100%;
  object-fit: contain;
}
```

The display: flex property will make the container a flex container, which allows you to control how its children are laid out. The flex-direction: column property will make the children of the container be laid out in a column, from top to bottom. The max-width: 100% and max-height: 100% properties will make the container resize to fit as much width or height available, respectively. The object-fit: contain property will ensure that the image and SVG inside the container are resized to fit the container while keeping their aspect ratio fixed.

```
 <div class="container">
  <img src="image.jpg" />
  <svg viewBox="0 0 100 100">
    <circle cx="50" cy="50" r="25" fill="red" />
  </svg>
</div>
```

This will create a container that contains an image and an SVG. The image and SVG will be resized to fit the container while keeping their aspect ratio fixed. The container will resize to fit as much width or height available.